# How to limit libp2p traffic or set maximum number of peers

Tags: nodes, network, libp2p, limit, peers

In running a polkadot node on the mainnet, i'd like to know how to limit the maximum number of peers, or if this functionality is already built into the protocol somehow. Since my network traffic is limited, I would prefer to either limit the rate of traffic to each peer, or to limit the number of peers my node can interface with. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The `polkadot` client supports limiting the number of incoming and outgoing peers. The default is currently at 25 each, but you can modify it using `--in-peers 10 --out-peers 10`.

More details can be obtained using `polkadot --help` command

Additionally, you should be careful not to decrease it too much neither. This would impact how quickly your node is able to stay in sync with the rest of the network.

Comment: Could I increase this count? Is there some max peers count?